# *** stack smashing detected ***: in gaussian elimination

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I am writing a code in C++ for gaussian elimination for pedagogical resons. There are no error in compilation time, but I get a stack smashing error when executing the program.

Here is what I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int i,j,l,n;
    double *c;
    int *indice;
    double a[2][2];

    n=2;
    a[1][1]=1;
    a[1][2]=2;
    a[2][1]=3;
    a[2][2]=4;

    c=new double[n];
    indice=new int[n];
    /*Inizialize indice*/
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){indice[i]=i;}
    /*find scaling factor*/
    for (i=0;i<n;i++){
        double c1=0;
        for (j=0;j<n;j++){
            double c0=abs(a[i][j]);
            if(c0>c1) c1=c0;}
        c[i]=c1;}
    /*find pivot*/
    int k=0;
    for(i=0;i<n-1;i++){
        double pi1=0;
        for(j=i;j<n;j++){
            double pi0=abs(a[indice[j]][i]);
            pi0/=c[indice[j]];
            if(pi0>pi1){
                pi1=pi0;
                k=j;}}
    /*interchange rows according to pivoting order*/
        int itemp=indice[i];
        indice[i]=indice[k];
        indice[k]=itemp;
        for(j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            double pj=a[indice[j]][i]/(a[indice[i]][i]);
    /*recording pivot ratio below diagonal*/
            a[indice[j]][i]=pj;
    /*modify other elements accordingly*/
            for(l=i+1;l<n;l++){
                a[indice[j]][l]-=pj*a[indice[i]][l];}}}

    delete c;
    delete indice;
    return 0;}
```

what does this mean and, where is my error?

Comment: Array indices in C++start at 0, not 1.  Also, if you used `std::vector` instead of raw pointers and arrays, you may have detected the error more easily (if you then used `vector::at()` to access the elements).

Comment: You also have the wrong form of `delete` (it should be `delete[ ]`).  Use `std::array` and/or `std::vector`, then you don't need to worry about these things.

Comment: Please consider using `std::array` instead of C-style arrays of fixed length. Former is just as fast but much safer.

Comment: [Example](https://www.ideone.com/dNFD6w).  Note the usage of `at()` to throw the exception, letting you know what the issue is.  In addition, note no usage of `new[]` or `delete[]`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have an error here:

```
double a[2][2];

a[1][1]=1;
a[1][2]=2;
a[2][1]=3;
a[2][2]=4;
```

The range of valid array indices is 0..1, but you are accessing elements at index 2, which is out of bounds.

What you probably want is:

```
a[0][0]=1;
a[0][1]=2;
a[1][0]=3;
a[1][1]=4;
```

or more succinctly:

```
double a[2][2] = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 } };
```

Comment: Thanks. The most stupid error...

Comment: I'm guessing you've come from a MATLAB background ? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

As already noted in another answer, you have indexes that go out of range, e.g. in your `a` matrix:

```
double a[2][2];

a[1][1]=1;
a[1][2]=2;
a[2][1]=3;
a[2][2]=4;
```

Valid indexes in this case are 0 and 1, *not* 2 (since in C++ indexes are 0-based).

I'd like to add that it may come in handy for you to use some matrix C++ *class* instead of raw C-style arrays. Your matrix class could define a custom index access method (even an overload of `operator()(int row, int column)` would do), and, in *debug* builds, you could check that the input indexes are inside valid ranges, and throw an exception or even just assert if they go out of bounds. In this way, it becomes easier to debug your code, as you can immediately spot the invalid indexes.

If you find that index checking noticeably slows down your production code, you could disable the index checking in release builds, and just leave them in debug builds.

Even using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) is better than raw C-style arrays, as you can use its `at()` method for accessing elements with *bounds checking*. (And I also think that `std::array`'s overloaded `operator[]` does some bounds checking in debug builds as well.)

---

As a side note, when you dynamically allocate array memory with `new[]`, you should release it with `delete[]`, not `delete`:

```
// Your code:
// delete c; 
// delete indice

// Fix:
delete[] c;
delete[] indice;
```

Even better, if you need dynamic memory allocation, consider using `std::vector` instead of raw `new[]`/`delete[]`.

Comment: Thanks for adding a more "holistic" answer!